# Why can't I integrate with respects to x for this volume of integration problem using shell's method?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Here is the graph of the problem, 
http://gyazo.com/5755dcfeea517756762943f704280d91

Here is the problem itself, http://gyazo.com/14bf36a0fa1968bcf41843e5f3510c82

This works if I integrate with respects to y but it does not work with respects to x even though I get the equation in the right form.
radius = 16-(16-x^2)
height = (4-x)

$$\int_{0}^{4} x^2*(4-x) dx$$

does not work, but 
 $$V = 2 \pi \int_0^{16}(16- y)(4 - x) \, dy, x = \sqrt{16 - y} = 204.8\pi $$
works

Why is is that? I'm putting in the same radius and the height values for the cylinder respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your integrand for the disk method is incorrect. i am not sure what the $x$ and $4-x$ represent there.

for the disk method you have $$V = \pi \int_0^4 (16 - y)^2 \, dx, y = 16 - x^2 = 204.8\pi$$ and for the shell method $$V = 2 \pi \int_0^{16}(16- y)(4 - x) \, dy, x = \sqrt{16 - y} = 204.8\pi $$

Comment: why can't I integrate with respects to x with the shell method? the radius of the cylinder being 16-(16-x^2) and the height being 4-x? I can understand why I can't do it with the disk method but for the cylinder method all I need is to give you the radius and the height of the cylinder and integrate it respectively.

Comment: @Josip,  you get shells when you integrate with respect to $y.$ you understand that. when you integrate with respect to $x,$ you get s disk of radius $16-(16-x^2) = x^2$ and thickness $dx$. the volume $dV = \pi (x^2)^2 \, dx = \pi x^4 \, dx$ and the range of $x$ is from $0$ to $4.$

Comment: I don't understand why it's a binary case, why does it only have to be discs if its with respects to x?

Comment: @Josip, to get a cylinder/shell, you need the the flat strip to be parallel to the axis of rotation. here axis of rotation is $y = 16$ you need strips parallel to the $x$-axis of width $dy$ and length $4-x$

Comment: I understand now, thank you.

Comment: My math textbook never explained that dy or dx meant thickness and after some googling it all makes sense, doing the problem in terms of dx would make no sense.